# Is it possible to send email notification for Input (GO/NOGO) from a pipeline

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, groovy

There is User input functionality in the declarative pipeline which prompt on the Jenkins console but it's a headache to login every time on console and select the appropriate action.

So I want to implement such a thing via mail for User input, For example User will get the Input via mail where there are two URL's for "Approval" or "Reject" respectively, If User select Approval then proceeded otherwise not. Here need to pass input on the pipeline on runtime.

Are there any plug-ins for same ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need any plugins.  You can send an e-mail from your Pipeline using [the `mail()` step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#mail-mail).  You can respond to the input step by using the REST API as documented in [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50606237/1824868).  Put the two together and you should be able to craft an e-mail that contains buttons for responding to the input.